# IntelliJ git push to alternative branch by default

Tags: git, intellij-idea, settings, push, default

[image: alternative branch push]

I want to make my IntelliJ use these settings by default, because we always push to `refs/for/[branch]` but I can't seem to find any info on how to do that. Does any one know if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. I recommend you vote for and watch the [Git Push dialog does not remember remote branch](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98693) feature request.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you could record a macro (*Edit > Macros*) to issue the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> key sequence to select the option and then enter your branch name. The map the macro to a shortcut (*Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap > Macros > ${yourMacro}*) You could even put the opening of the push dialog in the beginning of the macro so a single key mapping would open the dialog and set the alternative branch.